# recovering parameters after validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

1. I use "router.get" to capture all incoming requests matching /user/read/:user_id
2. In "router.param", I define a new object "user" with attribute name and age
3. Then in "router.get" I recover that user object with req.res.user.name to send a user's name back as a response.

According to [this tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4#route-with-parameters-/hello/:name), I should be able to use req.user.name. But it didn't work so I used req.res.user.name

**here is my question** :

is the "res" object in my "req" object the right location to recover my user from? In other words, I am wrong or is the tutorial wrong?

```
// route middleware to validate :id
router.param('user_id', function(res, req, next, user_id) {
  // validation on id
  var user = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    'age' : '3'
  };

  req.user = user;

  next();
});

router.get('/user/read/:user_id', function(req, res) {
  res.send({'user' : req.res.user.name});
});
```

update:

I'm using express 4.10.x

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but you've got your args to your callback backwards.

```
router.param('user_id', function(res, req, next, user_id) {
```

should be

```
router.param('user_id', function(req, res, next, user_id) {
```

The mixup results in you setting your fished out user object on the `response` object instead of the `request` object.